# How can I unjoin a join table relationship in rails/console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have Users who have and belong to many Objects.

So if I type :

```
User.find(2).objects
```

A series of objects will return.

How can I clear the relationship this User has with those objects, but not delete the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I know is to hit this from both sides like so :

First this :

```
@a = User.find(2)
@a.clear
@a.save
```

Then this :

```
Object.all.each{|a| a.users.delete(User.find(2)) if a.users.include?(User.find(2))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the relationship to an empty array.

```
User.find(2).tap do |u|
  u.objects = []
  u.save!
end
```